# Is __ILP32__ and __i386__ a valid configuration?

Tags: macos, x86, clang, c-preprocessor, linux-x32-abi

We took a bug report for some X32 code under Clang on OS X (the error is shown below). The user tried to compile code on an Intel x86_64 system using `-arch i386`. [X32 is 32-bit integers, longs and pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7635013).

According to the [System V Application Binary Interface, AMD64 (With LP64 and ILP32 Programming Models)](http://sites.google.com/site/x32abi/documents/abi.pdf) (page 104), the valid configurations are either `__ILP32__` alone, or `__ILP32__` and `__x86_64__` (and friends, like `amd64` in place of `__x86_64__`).

I also checked the [SYSTEM V APPLICATION BINARY INTERFACE for Intel386](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf), and it does not mention `__ILP32__` and friends. So I don't believe `__ILP32__` should be present on purely 32-bit systems.

I think the above should be enough to answer the question, but I am using Clang on an OS X system. The [OS X ABI Function Call Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/LowLevelABI/Mac_OS_X_ABI_Function_Calls.pdf) doe not discuss it, and often defers to the System V guides. However, the referenced System V guide is from 2003, which predates X32, so there is no treatment.

***My question is***, is `__ILP32__` and `__i386__` a valid combination or configuration?

---

For completeness, here is the code and compiler error. I'm not trying to solve this problem.

***Source Code***

`BOOL_X32` is defined when `__ILP32__` is defined in the environment.

```
asm volatile
(
    // save ebx in case -fPIC is being used
# if BOOL_X32 || BOOL_X64
    "pushq %%rbx; cpuid; mov %%ebx, %%edi; popq %%rbx"
# else // BOOL_X86
    "push %%ebx; cpuid; mov %%ebx, %%edi; pop %%ebx"
# endif
    : "=a" (output[0]), "=D" (output[1]), "=c" (output[2]), "=d" (output[3])
    : "a" (input), "c" (0)
);
```

***Compiler Error***

X32 is *mostly* 32-bit. However, when interacting with the stack using assembly language, we need to push/pop 64-bit registers and values.

```
$ make cpu.o
clang++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O2 -arch i386 -fPIC -pipe -c cpu.cpp
cpu.cpp:104:4: error: register %rbx is only available in 64-bit mode
                        "pushq %%rbx; cpuid; mov %%ebx, %%edi; popq %%rbx"
                        ^
<inline asm>:1:8: note: instantiated into assembly here
        pushq %rbx; cpuid; mov %ebx, %edi; popq %rbx
              ^~~~~
cpu.cpp:104:4: error: register %rbx is only available in 64-bit mode
                        "pushq %%rbx; cpuid; mov %%ebx, %%edi; popq %%rbx"
                        ^
<inline asm>:1:42: note: instantiated into assembly here
        pushq %rbx; cpuid; mov %ebx, %edi; popq %rbx
                                                ^~~~
2 errors generated.
```

---

Finally, here are Clang's preprocessor macros when using `-arch i386` on an x86_64 system:

```
$ clang++ -arch i386 -dM -E - < /dev/null | egrep -i "(86|64|ilp)"
#define _ILP32 1
#define __ILP32__ 1
...
#define __i386 1
#define __i386__ 1
#define i386 1
```

Comment: I'm confused here; let's back up a sec. The X32 architecture is not defined on Mac OS X. What are you trying to compile, and how?

Comment: @duskwuff - if its not defined, then why is Clang defining `__ILP32__` when `-arch i386` is used? (I also tried to improve the flow of the question, and added preprocessor output).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `__i386__` with `__ILP32__` is a perfectly valid configuration. It means that you are building code for 32-bit x86 on a compiler where `int`, `long`, and pointers are 32 bits wide.

While data model names like "ILP32" are usually used to describe 64-bit systems, the use of such a name, or the presence of a macro related to one, implies nothing at all about the instruction set. While the System V ABI does not state that this macro should be present on a 32-bit system, it also does not state that it must not be present!

Anyways. If you need to determine what instruction set is in use, use `__i386__` and `__x86_64__`; that's what they're there for.

Comment: So here's what I found (as you pointed out).... Yes, its a valid configuration, and the System V ABI does not prohibit it. In fact, its used in some ARM systems, too. With that said.... GCC, MSVC (Microsoft) and ICC (Intel) do not define it for 32-bit targets. GCC and ICC only define it for X32. Clang defines it for all 32-bit targets. I don't have a Comeau compiler to test.