# Why are system call numbers for `x86-64` and `x32` different but similar, and why are some not defined in unistd_x32.h?

Tags: linux, x86, x86-64, system-calls, linux-x32-abi

I have come across these files on Linux after reading more about system call numbers for particular architecture.

When I ran this command `locate unistd_64.h` it gives me a path to the system call file `/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h` but when I looked in the `asm` folder I found out there are other two files (`unistd_32.h`, `unistd_x32.h`) as well. I know that they are existed for different architecture.

What I observe is that the system call number for `unistd_64.h` and `unistd_32.h` are completely different.

```c
// unistd_64.h

#define __NR_read 0
#define __NR_write 1
#define __NR_open 2
#define __NR_close 3
#define __NR_stat 4
#define __NR_fstat 5

#define __NR_rt_sigaction 13       // this doesn't exist in unistd_x32
```

```c
// unistd_32.h

#define __NR_restart_syscall 0
#define __NR_exit 1
#define __NR_fork 2
#define __NR_read 3
#define __NR_write 4
#define __NR_open 5
```

And I believe it is because `unistd_32.h` supports `i386` architecture and I think it will only allow `4GB` of ram with `32 bit`, maybe and `unistd_64.h` supports `x86-64` architecture, and we can have 18-Quintillion bytes of RAM at maximum.

What I didn't understood exactly is that what is this `unistd_x32.h` file stands for? If we see it's content, it's pretty much similar to `unistd_64.h` so I guess system call numbers are the same after all, but it does have a new macro or variable `__X32_SYSCALL_BIT`. I don't understand why we are adding this?

```c
// unistd_x32.h

#define __NR_read (__X32_SYSCALL_BIT + 0)
#define __NR_write (__X32_SYSCALL_BIT + 1)
#define __NR_open (__X32_SYSCALL_BIT + 2)
#define __NR_close (__X32_SYSCALL_BIT + 3)
#define __NR_stat (__X32_SYSCALL_BIT + 4)
#define __NR_fstat (__X32_SYSCALL_BIT + 5)
```

Also, there are few system call numbers missing in `unistd_x32.h` version, like we have `#define __NR_rt_sigaction 13` this system call in `unistd_64.h` but not in `x32` version. There are many system calls like this. So If I assume that `x32` is basically `32 bit pointer architecture` but it can run on 64 bit version? So it can access only `4GB` of ram even if we have more RAM? Correct me if I am wrong in stating the question.

Comment: [difference between i386:x64-32 vs i386 vs i386:x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36347063/995714), [Difference between x86, x32, and x64 architectures?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7635013/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Linux's x32 ABI is an ILP32 ABI for 64-bit mode.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI.

As you can see, its syscall numbers are *not* all the same as for x86-64, because pointer width is different and arg-passing registers holding pointers might have high garbage in the top 32 bits.  The kernel needs to ignore this and only use the 32-bit pointer in the low half of the register.

Also some struct layouts maybe be different, as `long` is a 32-bit type in the x32 ABI.

Comment: So it means if I create a binary for `x32` it will work on both 32-bit architecture and 64-bit architecture, right?

Comment: @Visrut no, it's an entirely different ABI. It's 64-bit code with 32-bit pointers, so it obviously doesn't work in 32-bit platforms, and it isn't compatible with 64-bit ABI

Comment: @phuclv, but does this 64-bit code with 32-bit pointers can access more memory than 4 GB?

Comment: @Visrut no, pointers are 32-bit so the address space is only 4GB. It's for most normal applications where less than 4GB is required

Comment: @phuclv so it was created because legacy application from 32-bit architecture can also run on 64-bit systems, right?

Comment: no, as said, it's 64-bit code and doesn't run on 32-bit platforms so it has nothing to do with legacy 32-bit binary applications. It was created because it allows an app to utilize all 64-bit advantages (more registers, longer registers, RIP-addressing...) while using less memory than 64-bit code. Another advantage is ease to port 32-bit code that assumes ILP32 model, which is why many similar 32-bit-pointer-in-64-bit-mode in RISC architectures exist, like arm64ilp32 or mips64ilp32, even when they already have lots of registers