# C++ 32-bit vs 64-bit executable notation

Tags: c++, build, compilation, executable

How should executables for 32-bit and 64-bit be differentiated?
At the moment i use "-x86" for 32-bit and "-x64" for 64-bit. Is this correct or is there a standard for this kind of stuff?

Comment: I don't differentiate them by name but by the folder they are stored in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no standard as far as I am aware. But maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635013/difference-between-x86-x32-and-x64-architectures) answer will help you understand the differences.

If you want to make it clear to the user, which system architecture the executable is intended for, then adding "-32x" or "-64x" is clear enough.

Most people use the "-x86" and "-x86_64" as extensions however, and that also works. Although that more so describes the instruction set that the binary was compiled for, and by extension the architecture.